# how to scroll the content inside of a fixed-height container?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, height

I was wondering how I can realize with jQuery the simple example in the following image.

Basically it's a fixed-heigt container div and I wish to make the content inside of it (a list of paragraph) scrollable up/down by arrows.

I need arrows commands and no scrollbars and I wish to not use any plugin (if it's possible), like [this old dhtml](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/scrollc2.htm) example.

Consider that I don't know the exactly height of the entire content, because it's ajax loaded and so it can be variable.

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [scrollTo Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). But, If you want to bring native HTML scroll bars, then defining a overflow property, does the job for you.

```
div { overflow-y: scroll }
```

### Updates

---

I made a very simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/p3PQD/1/) of how the scroller can be create with just simple jQuery.

Another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/p3PQD/4/), with the scroll limits. Perfect to be called a plugin on the making.

### Update 2

What you are looking for is click and hold event, which is not available but, we can use `mousedown` event to build a workaround.

Check a udpated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/p3PQD/6/)

<sub>Basically, the idea is to start a interval on mousedown and clear on mouseup</sub>

Comment: Thx @Starx, but is this impossible to do without using a plugin?

Comment: I was looking for that to provide a "else" to my answer, but you were faster than me :)

Comment: @bobighorus, Ok I will create a simple demo using on JQuery

Comment: @Starx thanks so much Starx, consider that I don't know the height of the content before, because it can be variable.

Comment: thanks @Starx, it works; but is there a way to obtain a continuous scrolling keeping to press the arrow?

Comment: @bobighorus, use `mousedown` instead of `click`

Comment: Thank you so much @Starx, simple and clean, perfect! I accept your answer, you can vote for my question if you like. :)

Comment: @bobighorus, Did that 4 days ago, how about voting my answer too ;)

Comment: sorry @Starx but is it possible, according to you, to obtain the same with $(document).on(...) ?

Answer (score 2):

Is using the css property `overflow` a valid option?
This will do what you want, but it will show scrollbars (you can activate only one with overflow-x or overflow-y).

Comment: Yes, thank you @haltabush, I've just thought about this solution but I need arrows commands and no scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: visible;` should do it

Comment: there is a change in question, perhaps you would like to address it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scrollto plugin, it will make your life 1 million times easier

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

allows you to scroll inside a div with overflow set